# Processing: one object ignores if statement

Tags: java, processing

So I have my processing code and everything is working except for one PVector where its velocity isn't working properly and doesn't sync with the rest of the code. The code is for bouncing balls but the top left one drifts off off the screen for no apparent reason.

```
PVector location;
PVector velocity;
PVector location2;
PVector velocity2;
PVector location3;
PVector velocity3;
PVector location4;
PVector velocity4;
int size;
int acceleration;

void setup() {
  size(640,360);
  location = new PVector(0,180);
  location2 = new PVector(640,180);
  location3 = new PVector(0,180);
  location4 = new PVector(640,180);
  velocity = new PVector(10,-18);
  velocity2 = new PVector(-10,18);
  velocity3 = new PVector(-10,18);
  velocity4 = new PVector(10,-18);
  acceleration = 1;
  size = 16;
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  velocity.y=velocity.y+acceleration;
  velocity2.y=velocity2.y-acceleration;
  velocity3.y=velocity2.y-acceleration;
  velocity4.y=velocity4.y+acceleration;
  location.add(velocity);
  location2.add(velocity2);
  location3.add(velocity3);
  location4.add(velocity4);
  //size = size + 1;
  if ((location.x > 320) || (location.x < 0)) {
    velocity.x = velocity.x * -1;
  }
  if ((location2.x > width) || (location2.x < 320)) {
    velocity2.x = velocity2.x * -1;
  }
  if ((location3.x > 320) || (location3.x < 0)) {
    velocity3.x = velocity3.x * -1;
  }
  if ((location4.x > width) || (location4.x < 320)) {
    velocity4.x = velocity4.x * -1;
  }
  if ((location.y > height) || (location.y < 0)) {
    velocity.y = -18;
  }
  if ((location2.y > height) || (location2.y < 0)) {
    velocity2.y = 18;
  }
  if ((location3.y > height) || (location3.y < 0)) {
    velocity3.y = 18;
  }
  if ((location4.y > height) || (location4.y < 0)) {
    velocity4.y = -18;
  }

  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(location.x,location.y,size,size);
  ellipse(location2.x,location2.y,size,size);
  ellipse(location3.x,location3.y,size,size);
  ellipse(location4.x,location4.y,size,size);
}
```

Comment: *Code Snippet* is meant to be used with code which can be "run" by browsers, such as HTML/CSS/JavaScript. For examples of code like Java use *Code Sample* (not that it has anything to do with problem from your question).

Comment: Okay, so have you tried reducing your code to find where the problem is? Because this is a lot of manually copy-pasted duplication instead of a nice programmatic `ArrayList<PVector>` that you just loop through and do all the necessary things once. The offending dot is case 3, so delete all the 1/2/4 entries and see what happens (what happens is that the Processing IDE will immediately show you where you mistake is, and you should have tried that before posting to stackoverflow =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only thing which jumps out at me is that you are miss-assigning velocity here:

```
velocity.y=velocity.y+acceleration;
velocity2.y=velocity2.y-acceleration;
velocity3.y=velocity2.y-acceleration;  // this should be velocity3.y-acceleration
velocity4.y=velocity4.y+acceleration;
```

This is why copy-paste coding is generally considered to be a code smell.

Comment: Yeah if I wasn't so new to processing I probably would have done this much better, I'm surprised I managed to miss this error considering I read through it multiple time. Oh well, Thank You.